# counting alphabetic string length and turning into true/false statements

Tags: python, string

I have a simple question regarding a issue present in a personal project of mine. 
I have a hang man game im creating in python for fun and the hidden word originally presents
the user in the following method; say the word was hello, it would be '^^^^^', as every 
character is replaced by '^'. Now im trying to write a function that counts the amount of characters displayed in set string, so say i have a, and p guessed in apples and i now have the following view, 'app^^^',

Now heres my problem, I want to return a true or false boolean statement if more then half of the characters have been displayed so examples below;
'app^^^' = true because atleast 1/2 was displayed; therefore the return = true
but like, 'a^^^^^' = false, not 1/2 of the chars were displayed,

tbh i feel bad not posting anything but i came up with an idea of how to do it; 
so i felt like if i could len(app^^^) but remove the count of '^' then if the count is greater then half of the len(app^^^) without '^' removed, return true, else; return false. I believe it could work but not sure how to do it, thanks again guys.

Comment: lots of hangman questions today !

Answer (score 4):

Instead of counting the letters, count the `^` characters:

```
s = 'app^^^'

if s.count('^') >= len(s) / 2:
    # Half of the characters are `^`s
else :
    # Less than half ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that implements the solution you came up with would be:

```
def is_half_revealed(s):
    return len(s.rstrip('^')) / float(len(s)) * 2 >= 1
```

Although you should consider restructuring your code such that the data that stores "how much of the answer is revealed" is separate from the string that is displayed to the user, instead of checking that string directly.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution

```
def percent_solved(s):
    return 100 - s.count("^") * 100 / len(s)

if percent_solved(s) >= 50:
    ...
```